# How to get all records from Crystal Report using default parameter values

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report which has two paramaters: `{?EmailVerifyStatus}` and `{?Company}`. I want it so that when the two paramaters are blank the report gets all the records.
Here is my current code:

```
    (if {?EmailVerifyStatus}='Y' THEN {PREH.udEmailVerify}='Y' 
     ELSE IF {?EmailVerifyStatus}='N' THEN {PREH.udEmailVerify}='N' 
     ELSE  1=1) 
    and

   (if {?Company} <> '0' then not (IF "," & ToText({PREH.PRCo},0,'') & "," IN "," & {?Company}  & "," THEN 0=1 ELSE 1=1) else 1=1 )
```

But, it is only returning the records with a 'Y' value.

Comment: This code certainly wins my vote for the obfuscation contest :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if parameters have set a value with the `hasvalue()` function. Then you can do this:

```
(not(hasvalue({?EmailVerifyStatus})) or {PREH.udEmailVerify} = {?EmailVerifyStatus}) and
(not(hasvalue({?PRCo})) or {PREH.Co} = {?Company})
```

I dont understand your second condition ...

Comment: +1 I think you've got it, except the last line should be `not(hasvalue({?Company})) or {PREH.PRCo}={?Company}`

Comment: I get it Thanks. but my cumputer do not has hasvalue function.